# How to have a competitive research group in a school without a graduate program?

Tags: undergraduate, productivity, assistant-professor

I'm applying to assistant professor positions and my research plan is based on three main projects. My initial idea is to have 2 PhD students and one postdoc working on each project. However, there is an opening in a new school that doesn't have a graduate program yet. I'm planning to apply to this school but don't know how to explain my need for grad students. I'm almost sure I won't have sufficient start-up to hire 3 postdocs. I really want to have undergraduate researchers, as I'm a product of undergraduate research, but I believe the research output of my 5 initial years is way too important to have only undergrads and, say, 1-2 postdocs as my researcher assistants.

**EDITED:**

The importance of my productivity is related mainly to my research ambitions. At the same, this school is quite attractive to me because it's new. I think my voice will be heard much more in a new school. Do you think it's a good idea to search for potential collaborators in other departments of this school that have a graduate program and state this desire in my cover letter?

Comment: Oh, sorry, you are quite unrealistic, if you go to school without PhD programs, you should consider hiring more undergrad students. or colaborate on joint program if your uni have one.

Comment: _I believe the research output of my 5 initial years is way too important to have only undergrads_ — Presumably you mean "important for your tenure case".  But schools without graduate programs generally have different research expectations for tenure than schools with graduate programs.  Or perhaps you mean "important for my own research ambitions", in which case you might want to reconsider applying to schools that don't have the resources you need.

Comment: he needs to ajust expectation.

Comment: One of the key things that this school will be looking for in your research plan, is how you will _embrace_ your role as a faculty member at a school with no graduate program. Trying to "work around" this, rather than developing a research plan that takes _advantage_ of this, will not work in your favor.

Comment: @ziulfer, nobody would like to collaborate in a way that you expect. Basically, in that case, you would need to give up of the first mentor, advisor, and corresponding author, in order to have someone from another program. you need to start understanding what PhD advisor role mean

Comment: @ziulfer  states it is a new school, please clarify what you know of the school's or department's plans or expectations? As a *newly* set up(?) school or department, is it assuming that it will soon/eventually have PhD plans but it is still working on the state/government approvals for graduate programs. Or has it been set up to be primarily for a strong undergraduate and undergraduate research programs.

Comment: You should look and see how people at the school handle their research, and how other people at similar schools do their work. In general, undergrads are more common than postdocs. One prominent blogger who covers research at undergraduate institutions is Terry McGlynn (https://smallpondscience.com/2014/04/02/what-kind-of-faculty-job-do-you-want/); another is Chad Orzel (https://www.forbes.com/sites/chadorzel/2015/04/10/why-small-colleges-are-great-for-science-students/#1680bf137b9a)

Comment: Is it  now too late for an answer to be useful?

Comment: @Buffy, actually it is not. I currently have a permanent position in an undergraduate institution (not the one I was applying to at that time) and I'm struggling to do research with undergrads. Therefore, I would appreciate your advice.